# Spring Boot : Using JPA want to get the unique value from table

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table

CatID | CategoryName | scatID | subCategoryName
2        User            1        x
2        User            2        y
2        User            3        z
2        User            4        a 
2        User            5        b

I am able to get all the value in JSON formate using SpringBoot.

My Requirement :
I want to get the unique CategoryName attribute but in current scenario I am getting all User coming 5 times.

I am looking for solution. Please any one can help to get over using Spring Boot JPA implementation.

Comment: What is your requirement exactly?

Comment: Are you using JPA method or native query to get data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Query` annotation in your repository interface.
For example, below snippet code return all distinct `categoryName`.

Declare a simple bean class:

```
package com.example.test;

public class CategoryNameClass {
    private String CategoryName;

    public CategoryNameClass(String CategoryName) {
        this.CategoryName = CategoryName;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return CategoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        CategoryName = categoryName;
    }
}
```

Then use the below query:

```
public interface ARepo extends JpaRepository<A, String> {

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT new com.example.test.CategoryNameClass(a.categoryName) FROM A a ")
    List<CategoryNameClass> findAllCategoryName();
}
```

Comment: Hi Nasir,  I implemented but the data is not populating in JSON format with table attribute which is blocking me  to populate value in dropdown(AngularJS).                                                                                                         Value coming in format ["154,BBBBB","200,AAAAA"]

Comment: @Jaiswal: So you must create a new class. I edited my answer.