# How custom methods are implemented in JPARepositoryInterfaces?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have classes `Category` and `SubCategory`. Now in `SubCategoryRepository`, I have written a method something like -

```
@Repository
public interface SubCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<SubCategory, Long> {

    List<SubCategory> findByCategoryName(String categoryName);
}
```

How will this implementation work internally? How will it find based on category name. `Category` class is having field as   -

```
class Category {
    private String categoryName;
}
```

Comment: See answer of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61089428/spring-boot-using-jpa-want-to-get-the-unique-value-from-table/61090517#61090517

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are Spring Data repositories actually implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509882/how-are-spring-data-repositories-actually-implemented)